# AutodeskForge 504 Error when uploading files to BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We are uploading files to BIM360 using the Forge DataManagementAPI in a web application we have developed.
If I upload 10-20 files in a row in one process, I get a 504 error.
Each file size is less than 1M.

The files that caused the error are random. Upload all files successfully about once every 10 times.

The HTTP timeout for the application(nginx/php) has been extended to 2 minutes. However, there is no response for 2 minutes.

This event has not happened a month ago.
Has a limitation been added recently?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay,

We experienced issues on the date of your question, but it's already been solved. You should be able to upload your files through Data Management API normally as of now.

You can always refer to our [dashboard](https://health.autodesk.com) for any outages.

For 504 specifically, the orientation is to check if the file has been uploaded and, if not, try again.

Please, check [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/improving-app-resilience) for details on app resilience.

Also, we recently made public a new approach for uploading directly to S3, improving performance. Please refer [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried today and got the same 504 error.

The retry process is implemented in the application that uploads to BIM360, even after 3 retries I still get the 504 error.

It appears that this error has been occurring since around 2022/3/14.
Since the uploading application program has not been changed, I assume that something must have changed on the ForgeAPI side.

I have executed the SVF conversion process in BIM360, so I am not thinking about S3.

Comment: Please send your case to forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com so we can investigate further. If you can include the info for the request you're making, will be very helpful.